# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Failed to extract the cab file in the solution

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I have received the following error when I depoly the custom masterpage with css, images, javascript files:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Failed to extract
>   the cab file in the solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To work around this problem, remove any parentheses or @ in the names of SharePoint project items. Following link is helped me to solve the problem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330922.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I added fancybox js plugin to my sharepoint solution. The fancybox plugin that I added have fancybox_sprite@2x.png and fancybox_loading@2x.gif images. Thouse file names are problematic for SP solution.

I solved it by renaming names of problematic images (remove @) and update thouse images names in fancybox css file.